# Problemas al mostrar un botón en android

Tags: android

Tengo un template en Android, tengo una imagen un titulo y un listview pero al poner un botón debajo del listview se oculta en la pantalla, lo tengo que poner arriba del listview porque si no se oculta pero quisiera que estuviera abajo, eso me ha pasado regularmente cuando intento poner componentes debajo de un listview. Anexo mi código.

Gracias.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/tema_fondo">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearPadre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/tema_color_blanco_transparente"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tema_icono_paso_3" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/idHeaderCobertura"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cobertura" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textAseguradora"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity= "center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/idHeaderCobertura"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                android:text="Aseguradora"
                android:ems="18"/>


            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/coberturas_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textAseguradora"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
                android:divider="@null"
                tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_detalle_cobertura" />


            <Button
                android:text="Continuar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/radio_button_azul"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/coberturas_list"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:id="@+id/btnContinuar" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya tienes marcada una respuesta como válida pero te paso mi código del layout.
Con este código no tienes que dar un tamaño fijo al listview.

Se muestra el listview en pantalla completa con un botón en la zona inferior sobre el listview, pruébalo a ver si te gusta.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="6dip"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="net.pablo.android.app.LVActivity">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_below="@+id/inputSearch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listview"
    android:text="Mostrar mapa"
    android:id="@+id/btn_mapaCompleto"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Esta opción me parece mejor ya que no es buena práctica establecer un tamaño fijo al listview. @RogelioSanchez

Comment: Gracias al parecer cuando pongo el listview en un relative hace que se oculte el botón pero cuando se lo quito basándome en tu ejemplo el botón se ve bien

Answer (score 4):

Eso es porque al `ListView` le estas asignando el valor `wrap_content` en la propiedad `android:layout_height`, que es la que define la altura que tendrá el ListView. Al ser wrap_content, el ListView sera tan grande como el numero de elementos que posee. Si tu ListView posee 20 elementos, la lista se saldra de la pantalla y tendrás que hacer scroll para ver la lista completa. Y si tienes algún elemento debajo del ListView, este también se saldrá de la pantalla.

Para solucionar tu problema, asignale al ListView un tamaño fijo (estatico). Como por ejemplo, una altura de 400dp: `android:layout_height="400dp"`. Prueba con diferentes valores hasta que el ListView tenga un tamaño que deje espacio para color el botón debajo de el sin que se salga de la pantalla.

### Editada

Otra posible solucion es la siguiente. Coloca el `ListView` arriba del boton con la propiedad: `android:layout_above="@id/coberturas_list"`. De esa manera puedes usar `wrap_content` en el ListView y no tener que preocuparte por los tamaños de pantalla.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/coberturas_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textAseguradora"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_detalle_cobertura" />

<Button
    android:text="Continuar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/radio_button_azul"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_above="@+id/coberturas_list" <!--Coloca el listView arriba del boton-->
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:id="@+id/btnContinuar" />
```

Comment: Gracias es una solución buena, sin embargo de ser asi tengo que asegurarme que el tamaño de pantalla sea el menor posible por que al verlo en varios dispositivos podría afectar el tamaño fijo no es a si ?

Comment: @RogelioSanchez No es bueno establecer una medida fija, precisamente por lo que mencionas.

Answer (score 1):

El diseño de la interfaz tiene algunos problemas:

1. No es buena idea incluir un listView dentro de un ScrollView, ya que puede causar problemas con el scrolling, utiliza mejor un NestedScrollView.
2. El RelativeLayout dentro del LinearLayout está de más, ya que las únicas relaciones que tienes en cuenta son las verticales.

A continuación te dejo una versión simplificada del código, aunque diferente, que creo que se puede ajustar a tus necesidades.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearPadre"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tema_fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/tema_icono_paso_3" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idHeaderCobertura"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image1"
        android:src="@drawable/cobertura" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAseguradora"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/idHeaderCobertura"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:ems="18"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Aseguradora"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorGreen" />


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/coberturas_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textAseguradora"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnContinuar"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:divider="@null"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_detalle_cobertura" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnContinuar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/radio_button_azul"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Continuar"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias, pero le pongo el Scroll por si el tamaño de la pantalla es muy chico entonces con el scroll ya no se oculta, o como podría hacerlo compatible a cualquier pantalla ? he visto un poco de la documentación y creo que tengo que crear varias carpetas en donde voy poniendo los layouts